# Neo4j server plugin - function return value

Tags: neo4j

I am developing server plugin.
On documentation I read this :

> ensure that it can produce an (Iterable of) Node, Relationship or Path, any Java primitive or String or an instance of a org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Representation

What does it mean?
is it like always I have to return `public Iterable<SOMETHING_HERE> function(){}` Or I can return anything like like `public int function {}`

Thanks
Amit Aggarwal

Comment: Can I get JSON from my plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The valid return types of server plugins are:
* Node, Relationship, Path, java primitve, String or org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Representation
* or an iterable of the above

Since `int` is a java primitive, your plugin method can safely return a `int`. See https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial/blob/master/src/koan/java/org/neo4j/tutorial/koan13/AwesomenessServerPlugin.java for an example.